# Launching 49+ local kernels fails in 10.0.2

Tags: parallelization, version-10

I do large-ish parallel computations in Mathematica on quad socket 16 core nodes (64 physical cores).  In version 8.x, LaunchKernels[64] works reliably.  In version 10.0.2, LaunchKernels[48] works reliably, but 49+ usually fails with "Unable to connect to LinkObject".  It doesn't appear to be a timeout issue since launching 32, waiting a bit, and then launching the next 32 doesn't address the issue.  There are plenty of SubKernel licenses available.

I recognize this is a niche question and many people won't be able to test 64 local kernels, but I'd appreciate some suggestions about how to restore the parallel width I had in version 8 with version 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: What do `$ConfiguredKernels` and `Kernels[]` report?

Comment: What happens when you do 64 ParallelSubmit s and then WaitAll?

Comment: ConfiguredKernels is "64localkernels", although I set it to 48 when I'm not testing since it runs reliably. `Kernels[]` returns the active kernel list which is typically 45 to 52 kernels long after trying to launch 64. The ID of the failed kernels appears random. `WaitAll[Table[ParallelSubmit[ConfiguredKernels is "64 local kernels", although I set it to 48 when I'm not testing since it runs reliably.  Kernels[] returns the active kernel list which is typically 45 to 52 kernels long after trying to launch 64.  The ID of the failed kernels appears random.WaitAll[Table[ParallelSubmit[KernelID],{6

Comment: What is your OS?  With Linux machines, it's possible to run into ulimits.

Comment: I have seen this same problem in the past when creating huge numbers of MathLink connections (and you don't necessarily need to use that many kernels to do this). I don't know what causes it, but MathLink does seem to have difficulties with scalability in this scenario. By the way, could you please delete your comment above and add this information to the question? The MathJax formatting in the comment makes it unreadable and it messes up the rendering of the page. I do agree with other people that unless someone at WRI comes along, the question is probably not answerable by us as users.